# Angular the best solution for mapping objects, Class or service or static functions

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I need to map the json result to my local class object with converter, so i have some ideas for this:

- Create a Class "JsonResult2TableElementConverter"
- Create an injectable service which can include all the converters of the project
- Create the functions 'export let function convertJson2Table()' etc.

Can you tell me which is better, please? May be another one?
Do you have similar experience?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it's **better to make conversion on back-end side**. Server should return friendly DTO for the front-end side.

@JFPicard solution is good **only if you are using classes for entity models** in Angular. Then you can add methods in model like in ActiveDirectory pattern.

Unfortunately **a lot of people are using interfaces for entity models.** This approach has a lot of benefits in Angular. In this scenario would be better to wrap everything inside injectable service. Later you can mock up this service via Angular DI mechanism. It is:

- more testable
- more scalable
- you can easily change behavior via DI of Angular

Moving this logic to separated injectable service encapsulate this logic in separated layer. Encapsulating everything in your class will make this class fat and mocking this function will be not so easy in the future.

PS. Using pure typescript classes in Angular **which are not injectable** (so they are not Angular services) and **which contains ANY application logic** always make me scary. For me it is like "Helper" classes in ASP.NET created outside DI container which are really bigg pain later.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, getting a conversion class is going against Single Resposability principle of SOLID.

I think that the best approch is to have the local class object having a function or a constructor taking the JSON result to build the class.

So the responsability of the conversion will be on the class that use the data. Hence if you need to modify any logic, you only touch the concerned class, not a huge class with a lot of conversion functions.

@Karol Trybulec :

The local class should be returned by an injectable service as:

```
export class TestService {

    public constructor (private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    public callHttp (url: string, parameters: any): Observable<DTOTest> {
        return this.http.get(url, {params: parameters})
        .pipe<boolean>(map((result) => {

            return of(new DTOTest(result));
        }));
    }
}
```